# How can I display DialogFlow CX transitions defined in route groups on the grid?

Tags: dialogflow-cx

DialogFlow CX transitions defined in route groups are not displayed on the grid at all. Why is this?

We shouldn't have to open a page, then open a route group just to see what transitions are happening in each group. It really makes the grid and nodes useless especially in some cases where all transitions are happening from within route groups in a particular flow and page.

Is there anyway to force the display of transitions that were defined in route groups?

I created a flow that has a single page with multiple route groups. Each route group has transitions to other flows depending on the intent of the end user. I was hoping to see all of these transitions visually represented on the grid no different than how a route (outside of a route group) works.